# Link To Close Page Rails 4

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4..

I have opened a page using javascript like so

```
<%= link_to "how to choose a rating", ratingsystem_path, :onclick=>"window.open(this.href,'create_company', 'height=600, width=600');return false;" %>
```

But when I add a link to close that page

```
<%= link_to "Close page", :onclick => "window.close();" %>
```

It doesn't work. Am I doing this wrong? Maybe use an a tag instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
<%= link_to "Close page", :onclick => "window.close();" %>
```

Try this:

```
<%= link_to 'Close page', '_self', :onclick=>'window.close();' %>
```

You can replace `'_self'` with pass nothing like `''`

This works for me I hope for you the same ;)